# Converting WPF width/heigth into VB 6 width/heigth

Tags: wpf, vb6

My WPF controls need to expose a MinWidth and MinHeigth for the hosting VB 6 application to consume and honor. What's the most reliable way to convert from one to the other.

(If it will help, I can change the ScaleMode property in VB 6 to whatever.)

Answer (score 1):

- VB 6 Twips are in 1/1440 of an inch
- WPF uses 1 = 1/96th of an inches
- The ElementHost.Child property needs to be cast to a FrameworkElement
- The difference between the form's width and the client area width needs to be accounted for

Therfore the formula is

```
vbForm.Width = (WpfControl.MinWidth / 96 * 1440) + (vbForm.Width - vbForm.ScaleWidth)
```

Comment: +1 Although personally I would write `vbForm.ScaleWidth = (WpfControl.MinWidth * 1440) / 96` It's better to change ScaleWidth directly and also I prefer to use brackets to force evaluation order of `*` and `/`